# Getting started with writing MPI programs

Tags: development-environment, mpi, distributed-computing

In this coming semester, I am starting some research on large-scale distributed computing with MPI. What I am looking for help with is the initial stages, specifically getting a solid development environment set up. Does anyone have any recommendations for good tools to use for this?

I am also curious as to whether there exists a kind of simulator that would allow be to write MPI and distribute it to virtual (rather than physical) nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download a MPI library such as Open-MPI, MPICH, etc. and run it on a multi-core system (such as a recent desktop) with number of processes = number of cores. They would operate without a network interconnect (for instance, over shared memory). That should be enough to explore initially.

If you really want multiple nodes, you can experiment with multiple VMs with a VM network before actually moving on to a physical cluster. One of the VMs would have to be configured to act like a NFS server and the rest of the VMs could mount your home directories over NFS.

Comment: Does a VM network product/library already exist? I'm not sure I'm a skilled enough system-level hacker to cobble something like that together.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set this up with VMplayer / virtual box, each one has a GUI that can guide you through this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what is your favourite language.  I dove into MPI using python and the pypar module.  It lets you concentrate on MPI procedures without worrying too much about pointers and complicated c / c++ stuff.  MPI on a single machine is programmed no differently from MPI on 100s.  Getting cross machine setups is more about what MPI implementation and operating systems you use.

Comment: Hmm, C/C++ is my best language, so I'll probably start with that. Would you recommend pypar? I've been planning on learning Python anyway, I might as well learn a parallel lib with it.

Comment: mpi4py seems to have greater support.  But is hard to setup for windows.  I'm not sure where to go.